# set and get request without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have this code in my view

```
@if($order->accept == 1)
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/confirmed/{{$order->id}}";
    }, 12000);
</script>
```

@endif

and Controller

```
 public function confirmed($order_id)
{
    $order = Order::find($order_id);
    if ($order->accept == 4) {

        $message = '';
        return view('trip.html.trip', compact('order', 'message'));

    } else {
        return view('trip.html.trip', compact('order'));
    }
}
```

I want to check accept of my order without refresh page 
In this way I can but with refresh and I don't want it . Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you thought using ajax ?

Comment: You need to listen to server with an Ajax request...

Comment: I know but I dont know Ajax can you with Code help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Following will help u to understand ajax and render

```
<h1>helllo</h1>
<button onclick="getGoogle();">Get request</button>
<div id="google">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getGoogle(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://jsfiddle.net/user/login/",
    type:'get',
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
     document.getElementById('google').innerHTML = data; 
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uqw0L2r4/18/

I have loaded fiddle login page on click of button using **ajax** same way u have to add your laravel URL in url and append success(data)to your container.

EDIT- as per your timeout functionality

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url:"https://jsfiddle.net/user/login/",
            type:'get',
            success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
             document.getElementById('google').innerHTML = data; 
            }
          });
        },12000);
});
```

Hope so it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to stay away from AJAX because I don't really prefer it, for requests I should say.

What you're trying to do it refresh a element on a page, but not refresh the page. Sure thing!

Depending on how the server can serve (reply to) your requests defines what you can do. I will structure my answer based on what you have above using MkNxGn Proquest.

[MkNxGn.pro](https://mknxgn.pro) provides a sleek way to make XML HTTP requests via [MkNxGn Proquest](https://mknxgn.pro/scripts/Proquest_Proquest-v1.0.js).

Include this into your page `<script src="https://mknxgn.pro/scripts/Proquest_Proquest-v1.0.js"></script>`
This is your request. `Proquest("POST",
    URL_HERE,
    DATA,<br>
    HEADERS,
    RType,
    Ignore JSON errors,
    Callback);`

`window.setTimeout(function () { Proquest("GET", "http://localhost:8000/confirmed/" + OrderID, Skip, Skip, 'request', false, function(resp) {
     \*Resp = the request object so you can parse through it
     The request is made, with no further guidance on what your trying to do 
     I'm guessing as to what to do at this point*\
     document.getElementById('ThingToUpdate').innerHTML = resp.responseText
})}, 12000);`

will replace


`window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/confirmed/{{$order->id}}";
    }, 12000);`

You can see the docs for Proquest here [MkNxGn Proquest](https://mknxgn.pro/scripts/Proquest_Proquest-v1.0.js)

**Edit** was to include your interval to keep refreshing.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called AJAX. It stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. It allows you to preform requests without refreshing your webpage entirely.

Here is the W3Schools page on Get and Post AJAX request methods. (GET is a method for querying insecurely and POST is a secure method for sending form data to your controller)

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Here is the W3Schools example of a AJAX GET request which fires when you click a button.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

The difference between GET and POST.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp